# Finding custom-header.php in file manage on Wordpress Penscratch theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, file-manager

My website is www.rosstheexplorer.com.

I use Wordpress. I use the Penscratch theme. I have never consciously tweaked / altered file manager.

I made a change  to the custom-header.php and that change has caused me to be unable to load my site.

My webhost (Bluehost) said they could restore the file on file manager if I could tell them the directory for the file.

I have no idea what the directory is. I have always accessed the PHP files through Customise -> Appearance -> Editor.

Now I can no longer access Editor or Dashboard, my error has resulted in me being blocked from my site.

Can someone who has knowledge of the theme tell me where the custom-header.php file is kept?

The Bluehost customer service adviser earlier said

'I can see wp-blog-header.php but not custom-header.php.'

Last night I made a change to the custom-header.php file

The code was

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * @package Penscratch
 */

/**
 * Setup the WordPress core custom header feature.
 *
 * @uses penscratch_header_style()
 * @uses penscratch_admin_header_style()
 * @uses penscratch_admin_header_image()
 */
function penscratch_custom_header_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'custom-header', apply_filters( 'penscratch_custom_header_args', array(
        'default-image'          => '',
        'default-text-color'     => '666666',
        'width'                  => 937,
        'height'                 => 300,
        'flex-height'            => true,
        'wp-head-callback'       => 'penscratch_header_style',
        'admin-head-callback'    => 'penscratch_admin_header_style',
        'admin-preview-callback' => 'penscratch_admin_header_image',
    ) ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'penscratch_custom_header_setup' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'penscratch_header_style' ) ) :
/**
 * Styles the header image and text displayed on the blog
 *
 * @see penscratch_custom_header_setup().
 */
function penscratch_header_style() {
    $header_text_color = get_header_textcolor();

    // If no custom options for text are set, let's bail
    // get_header_textcolor() options: HEADER_TEXTCOLOR is default, hide text (returns 'blank') or any hex value
    if ( HEADER_TEXTCOLOR == $header_text_color ) {
        return;
    }

    // If we get this far, we have custom styles. Let's do this.
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
    <?php
        // Has the text been hidden?
        if ( 'blank' == $header_text_color ) :
    ?>
        .site-title,
        .site-description {
            position: absolute;
            clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
        }
    <?php
        // If the user has set a custom color for the text use that
        else :
    ?>
        .site-title a {
            color: #<?php echo $header_text_color; ?>;
        }
    <?php endif; ?>
    </style>
    <?php
}
endif; // penscratch_header_style

if ( ! function_exists( 'penscratch_admin_header_style' ) ) :
/**
 * Styles the header image displayed on the Appearance > Header admin panel.
 *
 * @see penscratch_custom_header_setup().
 */
function penscratch_admin_header_style() {
?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .appearance_page_custom-header #headimg {
            background: white;
            border: none;
            font-family: "Roboto Slab", Georgia, Times, serif;
            font-size: 15px;
            max-width: 1092px;
        }
        #headimg .site-branding-wrapper {
            border-bottom: 3px solid #eeeeee;
            margin: 0 0 27px;
            padding: 0 0 24px;
        }
        #headimg .site-branding-wrapper:before,
        #headimg .site-branding-wrapper:after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
        }
        #headimg .site-branding-wrapper:after {
            clear: both;
        }
        #headimg .site-branding {
            clear: both;
            margin-top: 54px;
            margin-bottom: 14px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #headimg h1 {
            clear: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 1.75em;
            font-weight: normal;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            line-height: 1;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #headimg a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        #desc {
            color: #999 !important;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 300;
            margin: 13px auto;
        }
        #headimg .site-logo {
            max-height: 150px;
            width: auto;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto 27px;
        }
        #headimg .custom-header {
            border-radius: 5px;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-bottom: 27px;
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
min-height:100px;
        }
    </style>
<?php
}
endif; // penscratch_admin_header_style

if ( ! function_exists( 'penscratch_admin_header_image' ) ) :
/**
 * Custom header image markup displayed on the Appearance > Header admin panel.
 *
 * @see penscratch_custom_header_setup().
 */
function penscratch_admin_header_image() {
    $style = sprintf( ' style="color:#%s;"', get_header_textcolor() );
?>
    <div id="headimg">
        <div class="site-branding-wrapper">
            <div class="site-branding">
                <?php if ( function_exists( 'jetpack_the_site_logo' ) ) jetpack_the_site_logo(); ?>
                <h1 class="displaying-header-text"><a id="name"<?php echo $style; ?> onclick="return false;" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
                <div class="displaying-header-text" id="desc"<?php echo $style; ?>><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
        <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" alt="" class="custom-header">
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php
}
endif; // penscratch_admin_header_image
```

I changed

```
  'width'                  => 937,
```

to

```
  'width'                  = 100%,
```

I believe this is causing my massive issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've made changes and you're not able to enter your website anymore, I have 2 solutions that might work for you very well since it worked for me.

I had the same problem as you do, I've tried to change the headers, even functions.php which lead me to lose the access of my website.

NOTE: Everytime you do changes to the source files, make sure you have a back-up.

METHOD #1

- Log in to your host
- Get FTP access from your hosting provider
- Use [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php) as FTP manager to log into your host provider
- Your website might be located in the "www" folder
- Navigate to your theme > wp-content > theme > theme_name Open the source files you've made changes before and add the back-up code there.

Once you've changed the code of source files you've edited before (in this case custom-header.php), of course if you're sure that custom-header.php is the problem then you'll be able to log in back to your wordpress account.

METHOD #2

- By using the FTP Client FileZilla which i mentioned before, download
  the wp-content (all the images) and re-install wordpress.
- Upon    re-installation add the wp-content back to the original
  directory and    re-create the website.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for peoples suggestions. The problem is now fixed.

My website provider is BlueHost.

I logged into BlueHost and found CPanel.

Here you are able to make changes to your website PHP files.