# Where Can I Download The Wordpress Penscratch Theme Files?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, file-manager

My website is www.rosstheexplorer.com.

I am fairly sure I have managed to corrupt / break my Penscratch Wordpress Theme.

When I try and load my website I am greeted with a white page.

Where can I redownload the Wordpress Penscratch theme files?

I have access to my file manager. I was hoping to be able to download the Penscratch php files and then upload them to my file manager.

Answer (score 1):

A simeple google search for you theme suggests this url
https://en-gb.wordpress.org/themes/penscratch/

You can click on download button and get the files then backup old files and replace the whole folder with downloaded version of theme. You may need to unzip it before uploading via ftp or if using filemanager make sure you place files in correct folder and unzip them properly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for peoples suggestions.

I used that site and it was what I needed. Although in the end I did not have to reupload the theme. I was able to correct my existing theme.

Look here for more explanation [Finding custom-header.php in file manage on Wordpress Penscratch theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44571516/finding-custom-header-php-in-file-manage-on-wordpress-penscratch-theme/44571694#44571694)